# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: utcDate

Tags: asp.net, iis

Our logs show hundreds of these errors after our deployment if users are on the site.   Anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Notes:

- We are using msdeploy, IIS 6
- I recently noticed that our web server's time is about 10 minutes behind the real time, I think that may have something to do with it.
- If I log into our site, seems like any file that depends on a WebResource or ScriptResource type file doesn't look right.
- Seems to fix itself after an IIS reset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try running

```
for %i in (*.dll) do copy /b %i+,,
```

in the Bin directory of the application.

it means that the assembly was built in future according to the webserver, the command above will 'touch' them so they appear to be of current date

Comment: Yeah, I think the future date on the dlls was the issue.

Comment: What a complete PITA. Why in the world should .Net care what date an assembly was built on?  BTW, +1 solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when i am using the Visual Studio inbuilt asp.net development server.  The server was throwing this error and was not loading the stylesheets.  This error occurred to me on Nov 7 at 1.10am US Central time.  I figured it had something to do with the Day light savings time and so, moved my computer's clock 1 hour ahead.  And Magic! --  it started working fine.  Wonder why that is !!

Comment: I've been having this issue for a couple days now too.

Comment: Had the same problem as we are moving to winter time tonight. Restarted my local web server and it loaded ok.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article, it seems that the problem is related to clock changes on the server, if asp.net founds dll built "in the future" it gives this error.

[time travel issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2011/10/30/time-travel-issue-specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-utcdate.aspx)